# Existence of geodesic frame

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I have a question about the answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/796608/if-gammak-ijp-0-then-nabla-e-ie-j-p-0?lq=1)

I don't know how to get the second equality in

> $$\nabla_{E_i} E_j (\gamma(t)) = \nabla_{\gamma'} E_j (\gamma(t)) = 0$$

I tried to use the fact that the covariant derivative of the geodesic $\gamma$ is zero and to write the tangent vector along the curve in terms of the $E_j$'s but it doesn't work out.

Comment: That follows from the definition of $E_j$'s: For each $q$, let $\gamma$ be the (unique) geodesic so that $\gamma(0) = p, \gamma(1) = q$. Then define $E_j(q)$ to be the parallel transport of $E_j(0)$ along $\gamma$. Thus for each $t$, we have $t\mapsto E_j(\gamma(t))$ is the parallel transport along $\gamma$, thus $\nabla_{\gamma'} E_j(\gamma(t)) = 0$ for all $t$.